# SQL query resulting in opening balance as 0

Tags: sql-server, datepart

```
SELECT 
    DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate) AS year, 
    DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate) AS month, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN G_L_EntryNo = 1 THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) + 
       SUM(CASE WHEN G_L_EntryNo > 1 AND PostingDate < DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS opening_balance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN G_L_EntryNo > 1 AND PostingDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1) THEN Amount ELSE 0 END) AS change
FROM 
    tblG_L_Entry
WHERE 
    G_L_AccountNo = '1010000'
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate)
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate);
```

Result

```
year    month   opening_balance change
---------------------------------------
2021    8   0.000   -15.000
2021    9   0.000   -5250.000
2021    10  0.000   -588.000
2021    11  0.000   -1141.980
2021    12  0.000   -2174.000
2022    1   0.000   -210.000
2022    2   0.000   -340.000
2022    3   0.000   -1560.000
```

Don't worry about minus change balance it is actual data .

Opening balance is not showing previous month ending balance as opening balance. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: PostingDate < DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1) --> this will evaluate to FALSE every time. Look into Analytic functions that can consider the ordering of your data, such as SUM or LAST_VALUE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example answer, it aims to shows how having "sample data" and "expected result" enables someone to trial their answer to your question(s). Note I really do NOT know what the "expected result" should be, so the result you see below may be wrong. If this is the case edit your question and add the correct "expected result" there (please don't use tiny comments for this). Here is some "sample data":

```
CREATE TABLE tblG_L_Entry (
    G_L_EntryNo INT,
    PostingDate DATE,
    Amount DECIMAL(10, 2),
    G_L_AccountNo VARCHAR(10)
);


INSERT INTO tblG_L_Entry (G_L_EntryNo, PostingDate, Amount, G_L_AccountNo)
VALUES 
    (2, '2021-08-01', -15.000, '1010000'),
    (2, '2021-09-01', -525, '1010000'),
    (2, '2021-10-01', -588.000, '1010000'),
    (2, '2021-11-01', -1141.980, '1010000'),
    (2, '2021-12-01', -2174.000, '1010000'),
    (2, '2022-01-01', -21, '1010000'),
    (2, '2022-02-01', -34, '1010000'),
    (2, '2022-03-01', -156, '1010000');
```

now an example query:

```
WITH MonthlyChanges
AS (
    SELECT
          DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate) AS year
        , DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate) AS month
        , SUM(CASE 
                WHEN G_L_EntryNo > 1
                    AND PostingDate >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1)
                    THEN Amount
                ELSE 0
                END) AS change
    FROM tblG_L_Entry
    WHERE G_L_AccountNo = '1010000'
    GROUP BY
          DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate)
        , DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate)
    )
SELECT
      year
    , month
    , change
    , SUM(change) OVER (
        ORDER BY year
            , month ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING
        ) AS opening_balance
FROM MonthlyChanges
ORDER BY
      year
    , month;
```

the result of that query:

| year | month | change | opening_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021 | 8 | -15.00 | -15.00 |
| 2021 | 9 | -525.00 | -540.00 |
| 2021 | 10 | -588.00 | -1128.00 |
| 2021 | 11 | -1141.98 | -2269.98 |
| 2021 | 12 | -2174.00 | -4443.98 |
| 2022 | 1 | -21.00 | -4464.98 |
| 2022 | 2 | -34.00 | -4498.98 |
| 2022 | 3 | -156.00 | -4654.98 |

You can trial (and/or amend) the above here: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/FejwHysH)

Answer (score 0):

No date can be less than the first day of the same month, but this is what your case expresion calls for:

```
AND PostingDate < DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1) THEN Amount
-- 2023-10-20 cannot be less than 2023-10-01
-- 2023-10-01 cannot be less than 2023-10-01
```

So you need to alter that case expression e.g. add 1 month to calculated date

```
AND PostingDate < DATEADD(m,1,DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YEAR, PostingDate), DATEPART(MONTH, PostingDate), 1)) THEN Amount
```

Comment: if i alter the expression as you suggested it gives me the same value of change

Comment: year month opening_balance change
2021 8 -15.000               -15.000
2021 9 -5250.000    -5250.000
2021 10 -588.000           -588.000

Comment: Your question was why your column is null. The change I included is just a suggestion. Btw. You have not proposed what the correct result should be.

Comment: it should be op balance fitst year 0 next year it should be the ending balance after the change should become op bal

Comment: if you want more than the question you asked, then BE SPECIFIC. Provide a table of results that you expect - IN THE QUESTION - not through these tiny comments. In truth  you should provide **"sample data"** for table tblG_L_Entry so that we can actually test a query and verify our result against your **"expected result"** if you remember to do that in future questions you will get faster/better answers as we do not have to interpret your words.  see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have added another "answer" to try and address the calculation of opening balance - but I remain unclear about the actual result you want.